# How do I completely uninstall VMware Workstation? No remaining files. Like it was never there

Tags: vmware

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 and having trouble with an "IO Error" that causes my VM to crash whenever I press the delete key for a bit too long. This wasn't a problem until two months ago. I'm not sure if it is caused by Ubuntu updates, VMware updates, or both.

I want to try uninstalling VMware Workstation and reinstalling to see if it will solve the problem. I have tried using this command, `vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation`, but it seems to leave behind some configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

the `apt-purge` command will go further than remove..

try `sudo apt purge package_name` and see that this get you

this purge command will delete also those configuration files this package/program would wrote on your system.. Best way to uninstalling and reinstall them.

Comment: Got this error for both vmware and vmware-workstation: "E: Unable to locate package vmware-workstation"